# what is d in time complexity of GBDT?

Tags: python, machine-learning, decision-tree, xgboost, gradient-descent

Is it a depth of the tree or dimensionality of the point.

1. The computation of pseudo residuals (r_im) is O(d) per point. So, for a dataset of size n, computing pseudo residuals is O(n*d) per iteration. Total time-complexity is O(n*d*m). Here d is dimensionality.
2. The computation of gamma_m's is very fast as it is a simple one-dimensional optimization problem where we are trying to find the best gamma_m which is a scalar. This is often a constant time step in practice.

So, overall, the constriction of the M decision trees sequentially takes more time O(n*lgn*d*M) than the above two steps which sum up to O(n*d*m+const). Since lg(n) is an additional term in the constriction of the M decision trees, O(n*lgn*d*M) + O(n*d*m+const) = O(n*lgn*d*M). Here d is a depth of decision trees